# Cannot launch iPad app onto iPad (Code Sign Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, provisioning-profile

I can't seem to launch an app onto my iPad.  The problem I think is coming from the fact that I've inherited this old app from a former coworker and was told to finish it, and he set up the project initially on a different profile.  Combine this with the fact that I'm a newb, and this is a disaster.

The error is :

```
Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.*' could not be found
```

I realize the object in quotes is the bundle ID.  So my question is - what should I be setting my bundle ID to to make this work?  I have a provisioning profile and an app ID for development, which I generated through XCode.  Perhaps there's another setting not set correctly, but I've read through the other stackoverflow answers and can't really understand why this bundle ID matters so much or where to get its value from.

Please help :-(

Comment: Did you enable your iPad as a developer device in Xcodes organizer? If not: Go to the Organizer > Devices > (select your device) > Use for development. And maybe clean your project (cmd+shift+k by default)

Comment: I think it's being used for development, since there is a green circle next to it?  I don't see any button that says "use for development."

Cleaning it did not solve the problem :-(

I still do not really understand the Bundle ID's significance...can you shed any light on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a provisioning profile and app ID that match the bundle ID of the app.  The provisioning profile needs to match a valid certificate on your computer.  Then you need to make sure that the provisioning profile is indicated for the correct build configuration (the standard two are Debug and Release) under your Build Settings.

Comment: How do I "make sure I have a provisioning profile and app ID that match the bundle ID of the app"?

Comment: On Apple's developer site, check your provisioning profile.  The status should be Active (with a little green dot).  You should also be able to view the matching certificates and devices attached to the profile.  Make sure that your device is included.  If everything looks good, I would delete your old profile (go to Organizer in XCode to do this), download this one, and then double-click on it to automatically install it.  It should show up as Valid in the XCode organizer.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Deleting the old provisioned profile and downloading/re-installing did the trick!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, add the device to your developer account (plenty of documentation from Apple on this).

In the Editor area of Xcode, select your target and click Build Settings.  Search for 'Code Signing'.  Change the Code Signing Identity is match your developer profile (or as short term solution, choose don't code sign).

Hope that helps!

Comment: The device is already added to the developer account, and I've already set the code signing identity to my developer profile.

As a side note, it says my ID ounder "identities without provisioning profiles" but I clearly have one on Apple's member portal - any idea why this is?